# Are the pets bound to a specific character or to the account?

Tags: path-of-exile

I don't understand something about the [pets](https://www.pathofexile.com/shop/category/pets): are they bound to one of your characters, or to your account?  How does the game manages it ?  It's not super clear to me, and [the wiki doesn't give any information about that](http://en.pathofexilewiki.com/wiki/Pets)...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I've just received this *ultra-fast* answer directly from their support:

> Hi Anto,
>
> They are account-bound, you can summon/dismiss them on any character
>   :)
>
> Cheers,
>   Samantha

Good news !